# Deleting old postgresql log files (Ubuntu)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, maintenance, disk-space

In a Ubuntu machine hosting a postgresql database, I have 16G space taken up at `/var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_log`. Apparently, log files from many months ago are being stored as well. I manually deleted a few to get rid of my `disk full` error. What's a robust way to delete old postgresql logs every week? Anything I can do in `postgresql.conf` to automate this process?

Currently I have the following in `postgresql.conf`:

```
#log_truncate_on_rotation = off         # If on, an existing log file with the
                                        # same name as the new log file will be
                                        # truncated rather than appended to.
                                        # But such truncation only occurs on
                                        # time-driven rotation, not on restarts
                                        # or size-driven rotation.  Default is
                                        # off, meaning append to existing files
                                        # in all cases.
#log_rotation_age = 1d                  # Automatic rotation of logfiles will
                                        # happen after that time.  0 disables.
log_rotation_size = 100MB               # Automatic rotation of logfiles will
                                        # happen after that much log output.
                                        # 0 disables.
```

I'm thinking I'll enable `log_rotation_age` and set its value to `30d`. But will this auto delete older log files?

Comment: Use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516384/linux-how-to-delete-multiple-files-at-once

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the configuration below;

```
log_truncate_on_rotation = on
log_rotation_age = 1d
log_filename = 'postgresql-%a.log'
log_rotation_size = 0  #just rotate daily
```

This says create a log file with a name like 'postgresql-Mon.log' and when rotation occurs override the old file with the same name.

Comment: It will work but its only single log file per server.

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL supports log rotation feature but doesn't support log removing feature. So user should remove logs manually or has to use `logrotate` utility to remove them.

Here is the [official document](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/logfile-maintenance.html).